# sleep while querying VirusTotal?

Tags: python, wait, sleep

I would like to use the VirusTotal API to check hash values against the VirusTotal database, but the VirusTotal public API limits the requests to 4 per minute.  The section of my code that compares my list of hash values (hash_list) against the database is as follows:

```
url = "https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report"
parameters = {"resource": hash_list,
              "apikey": "<API KEY HERE>"}
data = urllib.urlencode(parameters)
req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
json_out = response.read()
```

I need to figure out how to add a wait or sleep function into the code so it checks one hash from my hash_list, waits 15 seconds, then checks another hash, until the list is complete.  This will keep the queries to 4 per minute, but I can't figure out how to add the wait to get this to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import time

/code/

time.sleep(15)
```

Should work. Just add the `time.sleep()` snippet to the block to cause a delay.

Comment: Would I have to add it in a loop somehow so each result gets added to the json_out variable?

Or should I make it a function then just call it?

Comment: @P.J. Either way would work, really. Sticking it into a loop is perhaps the simplest way of doing it.

Answer (score -2):

```
def getdata(hash,apikey):
    params = {'apikey': apikey, 'resource':hash}
    headers = {"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate","User-Agent" : "gzip,  My Python requests library example client or username"}
    response_dict={}
    try:
        r = requests.get('https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report', params=params)
        if r.status_code == 403:
            return "Forbidden. You don't have enough privileges to make the request"
        elif  r.status_code == 204:
            return "Request rate limit exceeded"
        elif r.status_code == 400:
            return "Bad Request"
        elif r.status_code == 200:
            response_dict = r.json()
            return response_dict
    except Exception as e:
        return "API Request Error"
    return response_dict

for i in range(0,4):
   response_dict=getdata(hash,api_key)
time.sleep(56)
```

You can use a generator for the hash.

refer this repo [virustotal_apiclient](https://github.com/ajaykumarkk/virustotal_apiclient)